# Resolution switcher for HLS streaming

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video.js, http-live-streaming

i am trying to add up a quality picker for users to select desired quality on which they want to play the video using `video.js`.I have tried using 2 or 3 open source plugins all of which were deprecated or having old code which is not supported now and the worst thing is many of the of the files are missing in them.is there any solution to add up quality picker for `HLS` streaming on `video.js`?
Any help would be much appreciated
here is my sample code to play HLS streaming USING `video.js`

the current plugin i am using is : 
https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-quality-picker

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}" autoplay>
  <source src="legend_hls/legend_playlist.m3u8">

  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
<script>
  videojs('my-video').qualityPickerPlugin();
</script>
```

Comment: where does `qualityPickerPlugin` come from?

Comment: basically it comes from this plugin
https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-quality-picker
i am trying to use its example but not working
here is the link to its example
https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-quality-picker/blob/master/example/index.html

Comment: @Awaisfiaz The links you posted are broken.

Comment: @PranKumarSarkar seems like streamroot has privatized or removed the given repo do you need any help regarding this issue?

Comment: @Awais fiaz I am currently unable to implement manual video quality switching using video.js v7.8.0. Can you help me out?

Comment: Have you tried any pre-made plugin yet? you can try this too this seems pretty fine
https://github.com/chrisboustead/videojs-hls-quality-selector